# I tried using th:remove="all-but-first" in thymeleaf but it didn't work

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<td th:remove="all-but-first"> 
     <span th:each="groups : ${userView.user.groupMemberships}">
         <span th:text="${groups.group.name}"></span>;
    </span>
</td>
```

I was trying to display the first two rows returned in `th:each`, so I tried displaying just the first row at first and it didn't work.

How do you display just the first row and also what should we do if we want to display just the first two or three rows in `th:each`?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `th:remove` is used for removing prototyping generated tags.

As an example:

```
<table th:remove="all-but-first">
    <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
        <td th:text="${user.name}">John Apricot</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Martha Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Frederic Orange</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This means that will remove the second and third `tr`, leaving only the `tr` used for iteration. More details [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew20.html#allb).

So if you only want to display the first element of your collection, there is no need to perform the iteration, you could simply access it by index (or even key if it's a map).

Example:

```
<td> 
    <span th:text="${userView.user.groupMemberships[0].group.name}"></span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Displayed the first two elements of my collection and then gave a see more option to view the rest of the elements

`<td>
    <span th:each="groups,itrStatus : ${userView.user.groupMemberships}">
       <span th:if="${itrStatus.count < 3}">

          <span th:if="${itrStatus.count == 2}">,</span>
          <span th:text="${groups.group.name}"></span>
       </span>
       <span th:if="${itrStatus.count == 3}">
          , <a href="#" th:attr="data-value=${userView.user.userId}"  class="show-user-groups" data-toggle="modal" data-title="Add new user" data-target="#show-user-groups-modal">See more</a>
       </span>
   </span>
</td>`